# Vcl.Controls.TBalloonHint BringToFront?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, stayontop

In a Delphi XE2 program, a BalloonHint is partially hidden behind a window with AlwaysStayOnTop form style. So how can I bring the BalloonHint on top of the windows Z-order?

Comment: You have set the `Hint` to a certain text for the main form with `FormStyle` set to `fsStayOnTop` and for the `CustomHint` of that form you have used `TBalloonHint`, right ? If so, then I can't reproduce it in Delphi XE3.

Comment: @TLama The context is very complex, so it is not possible to reproduce it here. I call the BalloonHint with `BalloonHint.ShowHint(Rect);`. Isn't there a message I can send to BalloonHint to bring it on top?

Comment: @user1580348, I also could not reproduce this issue in XE3&XE4, I highly doubt XE2 is any different Balloon wise since TBalloonHint has been around for years.

Comment: Please note that the question is about how can I bring the BalloonHint to top. This does not necessarily include the reproducibility of a problem which is not necessarily inherent to the question.